# MariaDB event to automatically move data older than a specific time to another table without temporary table?

Tags: mariadb, transaction, isolation-level, mysql-event

I am trying to setup an event, that automatically moves data older than a specified amount of time from a heavily used table to some "archive" table to improve performance.

So far I've only come across answers, that are based on a `WHERE` clause that is used for both `INSERT INTO SELECT` and the `DELETE` statement. Since time passes between both statements, the `WHERE` clause could theoretically have different results and thus lead to data loss.

This is my event:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS archive_6_month_old_entries
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO
begin
START TRANSACTION;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE data_to_move 
SELECT *
FROM api_log
WHERE (datum - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH))) < 0 LIMIT 5000;

INSERT INTO api_log_archive
SELECT * FROM data_to_move;

DELETE
FROM api_log
WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM data_to_move);

COMMIT;
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Is there any way to do this without a temporary table?

Comment: Are you unable to simply `INSERT INTO `api_log_archive` from `api_log`?

Comment: but then we have the issue that, if in theory, the insert query takes up to 5 minutes, there will be a difference in the result between the `INSERT INTO` and the `DELETE` statement, leading to 5 minutes of lost data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say:

> but we have the issue that, if in theory, the insert query takes up to
> 5 minutes, there will be a difference in the result between the INSERT
> INTO and the DELETE statement, leading to 5 minutes of lost data.

No, you don't have to risk losing data! That's what [`TRANSACTION`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx#:%7E:text=MySQL%20transaction%20allows%20you%20to,database%20to%20its%20original%20state.)s are for!

InnoDB uses (Multi-Version Concurrency Control - [`MVCC`](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/innodb-mvcc-implementation-mechanism_8_8_30037516.html)). You should read up on this important topic in order to better exploit the capabilities of your server.

Something like this will work:

```
SET TRANSACTION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; 
  BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

  INSERT INTO api_log_archive
    SELECT *
    FROM api_log
    WHERE (datum - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH))) < 0; -- removed LIMIT 5000, it's not necessary

  DELETE FROM api_log
    WHERE (datum - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH))) < 0; -- removed LIMIT
  
  COMMIT;

SET TRANSACTION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;  -- or whatever your default is
```

Put this into an [`EVENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20Events%20are%20tasks%20that,a%20specific%20date%20and%20time.) and schedule it to run every day at (say) 03:30 every night.

Once you are happy that your event is working regularly at the time you require, then all you'll have to do is make monitoring it part of your daily monitoring routine.

#### Isolation levels

A brief explanation of the difference between the `READ COMMITTED` and the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation levels follows:

The default `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` on MariaDB is [READ COMMITTED](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-transactions-and-isolation-levels-for-sql-server-users/#:%7E:text=The%20default%2C%20the%20isolation%20level,with%20the%20tx_isolation%20system%20variable.).

So, in terminal one, I do the following

```
Terminal_1_> SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL;
```

Result:

```
 transaction_isolation
-----------------------
 read committed
(1 row)
```

That's what we want - so now we issue this command:

```
Terminal_1_> SELECT * FROM t;
```

Result:

```
 x |  y
---+-----
 1 | One
 2 | Two
(2 rows)
```

That's as we want it - so, now we delve into transactions as follows:

```
Terminal_1_> BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
Terminal_1_> SELECT * FROM t;
 x |  y
---+-----
 1 | One
 2 | Two
(2 rows)
```

Here, we "suspend" the transaction by switching to another terminal 2...

We run this query:

```
SELECT 
       pid, 
       age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), 
       usename, query 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE datname = 'test' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%'
ORDER BY query_start desc;
```

Result (active queries which are not the one above):

```
 pid  |       age       | usename  |      query
------+-----------------+----------+------------------
 3500 | 00:05:46.113281 | postgres | SELECT * FROM t;
(1 row)
```

So, we can see that my `SELECT * FROM t;` query is **still** active and is over 5 minutes old.

So, now, again in terminal 2, we insert a row into the table:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'Three');
```

And (still terminal 2), I check:

```
Terminal_2_> SELECT * FROM t;
 x |   y
---+-------
 1 | One
 2 | Two
 3 | Three
(3 rows)
```

And I go back to terminal 1 and issue a `SELECT * FROM t;` and the result is:

```
 x |   y
---+-------
 1 | One
 2 | Two
 3 | Three
(3 rows)
```

Now, to see the behaviour with `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` set to `SERIALIZABLE`.

We issue the command:

```
SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

I'm using a local PostgreSQL instance as that's the only thing I have running and running these sorts of commands isn't possible using a fiddle - the equivalents for MariaDB are [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-transaction/) - I leave it up to you to construct the required tests with MariaDB.

So, from termina1, we check our settings:

```
SELECT name, setting, short_desc FROM pg_settings WHERE name ILIKE ('default%transaction%o%');
```

Result:

```
             name              |   setting    |                          short_desc
-------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 default_transaction_isolation | serializable | Sets the transaction isolation level of each new transaction.
 default_transaction_read_only | off          | Sets the default read-only status of new transactions.
(2 rows)
```

So, we're good to go. From terminal_1_> (`SERIALIZABLE`) we run;

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM t;
```

Result:

```
 x |  y
---+-----
 1 | One
 2 | Two
(2 rows)
```

Now, from terminal_2_> we run our check on active queries again:

```
SELECT 
       pid, 
       age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), 
       usename, query 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE datname = 'test' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%'
ORDER BY query_start desc;
```

Result:

```
  pid  |       age       | usename  |      query
-------+-----------------+----------+------------------
 11064 | 00:03:37.694149 | postgres | SELECT * FROM t;
(1 row)
```

The query in terminal_1_> is sitting there and is now > 3mins old...

From terminal_2_> again, we update the table:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'Three');
```

and:

```
Terminal_2_> SELECT * FROM t;
 x |   y
---+-------
 1 | One
 2 | Two
 3 | Three
(3 rows)
```

Now we go **back** to terminal_1_> and run `SELECT * FROM t;` a **second time** within **the same** serializable transaction.

and we get:

```
Terminal_1_> SELECT * FROM t;
 x |  y
---+-----
 1 | One
 2 | Two
(2 rows)
```

The `SERIALIZABLE` transaction has the same view of table `t` that it had at the beginning of transaction, despite `terminal_2_>` having `INSERT`ed a new record...

I would urge you to experiment with differing setups to get to know your server's capabilities and how you can best exploit them...

In terms of your problem, what this means is that:

Scenario 1 (you keep the defaults on your server - i.e. `REPEATABLE READ`):

At time t1, you run this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE data_to_move 
SELECT *
FROM api_log
WHERE (datum - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH))) < 0 LIMIT 5000;
```

Say, for example, you `SELECT` 10 records. It's a log table, so it's constantly being updated...

At time t2, you `INSERT` into your archive table.

```
INSERT INTO api_log_archive
SELECT * FROM data_to_move;
```

At time t3, you DELETE from your api_log

```
DELETE
FROM api_log
WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM data_to_move);
```

Now, your process will **miss** any records that have aged to over 6 months between t1 and t3 - so, fine, you say, I'll pick them up the next time...

Scenario 2 (your run your archiving process with the `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` set to `SERIALIZABLE`).

For starters, you can cut out the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` phase as follows:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE        -- check out MariaDB syntax for this

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO api_log_archive 
  SELECT id
  FROM api_log
    WHERE (datum - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH))) < 0;

DELETE FROM api_log
WHERE id IN 
  SELECT id
  FROM api_log
    WHERE (datum - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH))) < 0;

COMMIT;

-- clear up - set your transaction defaults back to your preferred default...
```

The advantage of this is you don't have the overhead of creating a potentially large `TEMPORARY TABLE`, you reduce the number of steps from 3 to 2 and your system will be more robust.

- There is another possibility - you can lock your tables for the duration of your update - however, this means that no writes can occur to the `api_log` table during the time of your transaction - it's generally considered not to be good practice if it can be avoided. If you wish to explore this possibility, then you might like to ask another question...

This [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=38854e69d858345a59b0f3f5d8ded30e) should help clarify things - PostgreSQL has the useful (and intelligently explicit) functions [`TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-current_timestamp/) and [`CLOCK_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/clock_timestamp-function.php) - with `READ COMMITTED` any query sees the data as of `CLOCK_TIMESTAMP` and a `SERIALIZABLE` transaction sees the data as of `TRANSACTION TIMESTAMP`!

Comment: so the trick is to use both `SET TRANSACTION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; ` and `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, got it!

Comment: That's what I would do - don't forget to set the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED back afterwards... But, if you're doing it as an EVENT, I don't **think** it should impact on other transactions - you might want to test? I'll put the text from some of the comments into the body of the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This can be significantly sped up (if you have `INDEX(datum)`):

```
WHERE (datum - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)))
      < 0 LIMIT
```

-->

```
WHERE datum > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

Partitioning is the ultimate speedup:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Is your table have some id or timestamp that is guaranteed to be unique and monotonic?  If so, first get the end value via `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5000`, then use that value as the range for both the `INSERT...SELECT` and for the `DELETE`.

For that matter, can you perhaps fetch the *day* 6 months ago instead of fetching the *second*?

Fetch this once and use it for both queries:

```
SET @ago = NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH;
```

then...

```
repeat
    INSERT INTO ...
        SELECT ... WHERE datum < @ago  LIMIT 1000;
until no more

repeat
    DELETE FROM ... WHERE datum < @ago  LIMIT 1000;
until no more
```

Better yet would be put that with my previous suggestion:

```
repeat
    SELECT @z := id FROM ..  WHERE datum < @ago
        ORDER BY id  LIMIT 1000, 1;

    INSERT INTO ...
        SELECT ... WHERE datum < @ago
                     AND id <= @id;

    DELETE FROM ... WHERE WHERE datum < @ago
                      AND id <= @id;
until no more
```

You do have `INDEX(datum)`?

Comment: The table has multiple million entries, I first need to clean it, then I can think about applying any kind of partitioning. thank you for your optimizations, I will add them to my query.

and yes, I have INDEX(datum) but it is not part of the primary key (as of yet).

Comment: @Theo - Or...  Create a new table with partitioning, then `INSERT` into it the rows you want to keep.  Then `RENAME TABLE` to move it into place.  Probably the fastest and does it all at once.  (Yes, it would be better to get a feel for each part first.)